# Calling overridden methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, superclass

i tried to find a way to call overridden method of superclass in JS and got this.

```
function A() {
    this.superclass = new Array(A.prototype);
}
A.prototype.call_method = function(method, args, pos) {
    if (!(pos >= 0)) pos = this.superclass.length - 1;
    while (!this.superclass[pos].hasOwnProperty(method)) if ((--pos) < 0) return;
    if (this.superclass[pos][method]) this.superclass[pos][method].apply(this, args);
    if (pos) this.call_method(method, args, pos - 1);
}
A.prototype.add = function() {
    this.superclass.push(arguments.callee.caller.prototype);
}
A.prototype.test = function(a, b, c) {
    alert("test of A ");
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
    this.add();
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.test1 = function(a, b, c) {
    alert("test of B ");
}

function C() {
    B.call(this);
    this.add();
}
C.prototype = new B();
C.prototype.constructor = C;
C.prototype.test = function(a, b, c) {
    alert("test of C");
}

var aa = new C();
aa.call_method("test", [1, 2, 3]);
```

What do You think, is it ok ?
Or maybe it can produce 'memory leaks' (reference to own prototype)?
Thanks a lot

---

Thank You for your reply,
i tried Your code out .
But if I subclass SubClass, for examle var a= SubClass1(),
( SubClass1 has its own foo())

and call a.foo(), then only SubClass1 and BaseClass foo's will be called,

not SubClass foo()
Code:

```
function BaseClass() { } BaseClass.prototype.foo = function() {     
  alert('called BaseClass.foo'); 
};  
SubClass = function() { }; 
SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass; 
SubClass.prototype.foo = function() {     
    alert('called SubClass.foo');      
    // calling super.foo();   
    this.constructor.prototype.foo.call(this); 
}; 
SubClass1 = function() { }; 
SubClass1.prototype = new SubClass; 
SubClass1.prototype.foo = function() {     
    alert('called SubClass1.foo');      
    // calling super.foo();   
    this.constructor.prototype.foo.call(this); 
}; 
var a=new SubClass1();
a.foo();
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your code in short?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but maybe `Object.getPrototypeOf` can help you out...

Answer (score 7):

You can use a property to store the class' parent and call methods directly on the parent class:

```
function BaseClass() {
}
BaseClass.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('called BaseClass.foo');
};

SubClass = function() {
};
SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass;
SubClass.prototype.__super__ = BaseClass;
SubClass.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('called SubClass.foo');

    // calling super.foo();
    this.__super__.prototype.foo.call(this);
};
```

You can add a little abstraction:

```
// The `clazz` parameter allows super-classes to use super() too.
// It should be the calling class
BaseClass.prototype.super = function(clazz, functionName) {
    // take all the arguments after functionName
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    // call the function on super's prototype
    clazz.prototype.__super__.prototype[functionName].apply(this, args);
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
SubClass.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('called SubClass.foo');

    // calling super.foo();
    // Pass the calling class as first parameter
    this.super(SubClass, 'foo');
};
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWZP6/2/

### In CoffeeScript

In coffee script you can use the [`super()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#classes) construct:

```
class BaseClass
    foo: -> console.log('called BaseClass.foo')

class SubClass extends BaseClass
    foo: ->
        console.log('called SubClass.foo')
        super()
```

Comment: Thank You all , but my problem is to get 3 or more clases(subclasses),
so that they all have a method with the same name.
A()->B()->C(), all of them have method foo(), and if i call C.foo(), then B.foo() and A.foo() should be called too.
my Code works, but maybe it is really bad... that was the question

Comment: I've updated the answer and the example code at http://jsfiddle.net/ZWZP6/2/ ; this works with more than one level of inheritance

Comment: I think you've just sold me on CoffeeScript

Answer (score 0):

In 2015 version 6 of ECMAScript was released. One of the new features was native [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

The parent class is accessible via the new [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) keyword.

Your example of a sub-class of a sub-class of a class could be written as:

```js
class A {
  foo() {
    console.log('A');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  foo() {
    super.foo();
    console.log('B');
  }
}

class C extends B {
  foo() {
    super.foo();
    console.log('C');
  }
}

const o = new C();
o.foo();
```